# Auto-splitting the terminal at the beginning

Tags: tmux

I'm using `tmux` terminal multiplexer and I often use the same layout. I cross-split the terminal and launch `mc` (Midnight commander) in one quadrand.

How do I configure this in tmux.conf, so I don't need to do this everytime when I open the terminal? Or should I use shell commands instead? What's the best way to do this? Ta.

Comment: Check out the `neww` and `split-window` commands.

Comment: @oakad Thanks a lot. What is the command for moving between the panes?? I usually use the key-shortcut Ctrl+b w/ arrows.

Comment: `select-window`? `select-pane`? Why not read the manual, it is very well written: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html